# ASP.NET CORE MVC - token from other rest - auth attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, token

Welcome,

I have project asp.net core mvc 3.1 and I have full rest api in PHP. In my .net app I would like to use the token downloaded from api in my .net project.

My goal is to make my own auth attribute which will get the user from usercontext(httpcontext?) and check if he has a token.
I spent several hours searching for a solution but I found nothing similar.
Has anyone encountered a similar problem? Please help.

For example I can use Authorize attribute [example attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0RlL.png) with UserManager and SignInManger [example managers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtyO7.png).

I need the same solution but for tokens. Every user after login receive token from rest api written in php. I need to somehow keep this token and bind it with logged user. Also I would like use attribute in my controller/action which automatically detect if concrete user has token.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. You want to authorize users by checking Request? if yes, in this way you can send your token in HTTP header and by writing a middleware you can check it.

Comment: Explain the flow of the HTTP request. Which app is serving as the server? Which is the client?

Comment: Gentlemen. I add some more information in description.

Answer (score 0):

> I need the same solution but for tokens. Every user after login receive token from rest api written in php. I need to somehow keep this token and bind it with logged user. Also I would like use attribute in my controller/action which automatically detect if concrete user has token.

There are lots of ways to store the state for user level in asp.net core. For example, using cookie, session and HttpContext.Items etc. You can refer to the document below for the details:

[Session and state management in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1#state-management)

And if you are using session, then you need to implement the customer policy authorization to verify the token as your requirement. To use IHttpContextAcessor to access session from [HttpContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext?view=aspnetcore-3.1) inside of an authorization handler, see

[Access MVC request context in handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-3.1#access-mvc-request-context-in-handlers)

[Use HttpContext from custom components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-httpcontext-from-middleware)